# Como fazer o sweetalert para confirmação de exclusão de registros?

Tags: php, javascript, sweetalert

Olá,
Gostaria de fazer um sweetalert para excluir os registros do meu site, mas não sei como fazer pois não entendo de javascript...
Alguém pode me dar uma luz ?

**Minha página class/crud.php onde ficam as querys (a parte do delete):**

```
public function excluirAluno($idAluno){
global $pdo;

$sql = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM alunos WHERE id_alunos = '$idAluno'");
$sql->execute();
}

public function excluirPagamentos($idAluno){
global $pdo;

$sql = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM pagamentos WHERE alunos_id = '$idAluno'");
$sql->execute();
     }
```

**E aqui vem a home.php onde mostram os registros (apenas o código php):**

```
<?php
include_once 'config.php';
global $pdo;

$sql = "select * from alunos left join pagamentos on id_alunos = 
pagamentos.alunos_id order by nome";


$sql = $pdo->query($sql);

if ($sql->rowCount() > 0)
{

foreach ($sql->fetchAll() as $aluno):
?>

  <tr>
  <td> <?php echo $aluno['nome']; ?> </td>
  <td> <?php echo $aluno['fone']; ?> </td>
  <td> <?php echo $aluno['email']; ?> </td>
  <td> <?php echo $aluno['situacao_aluno']; ?>
  </td>

  <?php

 echo "<td><a href='editar.php?id_alunos=" . $aluno['id_alunos'] . "' 
 class='btn btn-dark' role='button'>Editar</a></td>";

 echo "<td><a href='delete_submit.php?id_alunos=" . $aluno['id_alunos'] . "' 
 class='btn btn-danger'>Deletar</a></td>";

 echo "</tr>";
  ?>
  </tr>

  <?php
  endforeach;
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: Olá, procure pela parte de confirm dialog na documentação, acho que pode ser útil no seu caso. https://sweetalert2.github.io/#examples

Comment: @renanzin obrigada!!! Achei o exemplo....só que agora não sei onde aplicá-lo no meu código...acredito que seja na minha home.php onde tem o botão excluir, mas ai o código sweetalert entra no meu código php ?

Comment: Veja como incluir um código Javascript em sua página, após isso, você pode inserir o código do sweet alert e elaborar sua lógica para exclusão.. http://tableless.github.io/iniciantes/manual/js/inserindo-js.html

Comment: Obrigada @re!!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

```
swal("Atenção","Deseja Excluir?", {
            closeOnClickOutside: false, //não fecha o swal se clicar fora
            dangerMode: true, //danger mode pra chamar atenção
            closeOnEsc: false, // não deixa fechar no esc
            buttons: {
                cancelar: { // cria o botão para cancelar (q vc pode chamar de "NÂO"
                    text: "Cancelar", // texto do botão
                    value: "cancelar", // valor pra gente testar la em baixo
                    className: "swal-button--danger", // classe do botão css
                },
                confirmar: { // botao confirmar
                    text: "Confirmar", // texto do botão
                    value: "confirmar", // valor pra gente testar la em baixo
                    className: "swal-button--confirm", // classe do botão css
                },

            },
            icon: "info", // icone do swal
            })
            .then((value) => { // aqui é a ação !
                if(value == "confirmar"){ // se clicou em "confirmar" chama o ajax que faz a exclusão.
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "sua_delete_url.php"
                        data: $("#seuform").serialize(), // seu form serializado
                        success: function(ret){

                              // aqui você trata o retorno da sua pagina e exibe mensagem de erro ou sucesso, de acordo com os seus critérios de exclusão e etc...       

                        },
                        error: function(){
                            swal("Atenção","Erro ao excluir","error"); //erro HTTP
                        }
                    }); 
                }
            });
```